# Google +1 button in Android app does not change count

Tags: android, google-plus-one

I followed [the standard procedure](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend) to add a Google plus button:

```
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton 
    xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
          android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            plus:annotation="bubble"
            plus:size="standard(none)" />
```

It is linked to the app's Google Play page. It is initialized in onResume as recommended:

```
 _PlusOneButton.initialize("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mydomain.myapp", 0);
```

The button gets the count correctly initially, but the count never changes. The Google Play page shows the count keeps changing (increasing) as expected.  I have been curious about activityRequestCode in initialize (String url, int activityRequestCode).  I do not know what it does.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Might be a stupid comment, but since you didn't specify it yourself, i'll have to ask..
Did you remember to change the "net.mydomain.myapp" to YOUR own app domain and name?

Comment: "net.mydomain.myapp" is the only part of the code that has been modified for the post.  The actual URL is the real URL of the app's page.  As stated in the post, it worked initially- it got the correct count.  However, the count has never changed since.

Comment: No.  I removed the count from the display.  I have not tested the count since then, so I do not know if it is working now.